# What is the mathematical difference between Cpk and Ppk?

Tags: quality-control

I am trying to understand the mathematical difference between Cpk and Ppk used in Statistical Process Control (SPC). I have gone through the web but all I found a confusing and more confusing theoretical implication of the two. Before I can try to induce their application, I will need to find out What mathematical difference are? And even that I am not able to find a good source. I have googled and wiki-ed.

My understanding is Ppk uses all data in calculating its standard deviation and Cpk uses all data but minus 1 in calculating its standard deviation. Is that it?

For example, if I have a set of data "5" , "4" , "5.5" , "4.5" , "3.5" what is their Cpk and Ppk?

Comment: What is Cpk and Ppk? Could you provide links?

Comment: They are indicators used in SPC (Statistical Process Control). You can easily wiki or google "Statistical Process Control".

Answer (score 5):

The difference is in the way $\sigma$ is calculated. For an *out of control process*, AIAG (Automotive Industry Action Group) suggests using 
$\hat{\sigma}=S=\sqrt{\frac{1}{mn-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(X_{ij}-\bar{\bar{X}})^2}$
as an estimator of the standard deviation (*long-term variability*).

where $\bar{\bar{X}}=\frac{1}{mn}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{ij}$, for $m$ samples of size $n$.

In that case we are talking about *process performance indexes* ($P_p, P_{pk}$).

On the contrary, for an *in control process*, $\sigma$ should be estimated by $\frac{\bar S}{c_4}$ or $\frac{\bar{R}}{d_2}$ (*short-term variability*) and we are talking about *process capability indices* ($C_p, C_{pk}$).

Of course, for processes that are in control, process performance and process capability indexes will be almost identical. It should be noted that several prominent
statisticians suggest not using any performance indicators when the process
is out of control, because the process capability is meaningful only for
processes that are in control.

Comment: thanks for answering. But what is C4 and C5? What do you mean by "in control"? Do you mean control by machine?

Comment: c4 and d2 are constants. Look for them here http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/IQCC/html/00Index.html 
As for "in and out of control" processes, I think it is too elementary in SPC. Search for "in control" here as an example http://www.cheresources.com/spczz.shtml